# TallComponents.PDF.Document Error: "the document is corrupt, rebuilding failed"

Tags: arrays, pdf, stream, pdf-generation, memorystream

I'm getting exception "the document is corrupt, rebuilding failed",
while instantiating TallComponents.PDF.Document from MemoryStream.

The byteResponse is good. that is, the document is NOT Corrupted.
However, I am running this method in loop to create multiple PDFs.

Am I missing something? Do I need to make any additional checks?

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteResponse, true))
{
     var pdf = new TallComponents.PDF.Document(stream);
```

[image]

Comment: *"The byteResponse is good"* - how did you test that?

Comment: yes, if we return same byte array from web application with MIME type application/pdf, we are able to browse the pdf. But, not able to save the same byte array as pdf document.  I am running this method in loop to create multiple PDFs. Is there any issue with closing stream or TallComponent pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

Please set stream.Position = 0; before creating the instance of Tall Pdf.
You are doing it but after the instance has been created.